# passing hash and array to function problem

Tags: perl

I am trying to pass `ConnectODBC(%settings , @connectionString);` hash abd then array

In the function I load then like `my (%settings , @connectionString) = @_;`

for hash i get the right values but for `print $connectionString[0] . ".\n";`

I get `Use of uninitialized value $conection[0] in concatenation (.)`

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are assigning to a list/hash, the first argument absorbs it all.

```
my %h1 = ( key => value );
my @a1 = (1, 2 );
my ( @a2, %h2 ) = ( @a1, %h1 );
# @a2 now contains (1,2,key,value) and %h2 is undefined.
```

To obtain what you want, you should pass references instead.

```
ConnectODBC( \%settings , \@connectionString);
sub ConnectODBC {
    my ( $setting_ref, $connection_ref ) = @_;
    my %settings = %$setting_ref;
    my @connectionString = @$connection_ref;
}
```

I should note that making hashes and arrays out of the references in the subroutine probably is unnecessary. You can access the settings directly from the reference. `$setting_ref->{key}` is the same as `$settings{key}`.